# How to implement a python list of position-aware items

Tags: python, list, data-structures

I have a requirement for a certain special case(s) of list of where the list items would be aware (have an attribute / property) that tells:

- whether the item is the last item in the list
- their index or "enumerator" in the list

The approaches I can think of off the top of my head are:

1. Overriding `__setitem__`, `__add__`, `insert`, `append`, `pop` et. al
2. Not store them in python lists, but have a "next" attribute pointing to the next item.
3. Adding helper functions to sync the index attributes before evaluation (or after update)
4. Don't store them as attributes but handle it "outside" the classes

1) seems like most pythonic approach, but would require overriding quite a few methods. 2) has the problem of having to re-implement the said methods (and doesn't really help with the indexes if I want to `insert()` or `pop()`)
3) & 4) have pitfall of "you must remember to call X before doing Y"

All items in the said lists will (or should) always be instances of the same class.

Is there a known design pattern for this or a pythonic approach that I'm not aware of?

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with Marcin, but maybe if you give further details of your use case(s) and hoped-for API (as in, what syntax do you wish to be able to write, with what results), I could conceivably try to give a more helpful answer.

Comment: @Marcin RFC 5996 implementation - creating SAPayload / Proposal / Transform classes that would have a self-contained `as_data()` function (e.g. one that could be made a `property`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a requirement for a certain special case(s) of list of where the list items would be aware (have an attribute / property) that tells:
>     whether the item is the last item in the list; [and]
>     their index or "enumerator" in the list

No you don't. You have a requirement that some other part of your code deal appropriately with the last element, or work with the index.

There is no clean way to do what you ask, because it should be the responsibility of the list object to keep track of these things. AT MOST the list items should have a property which holds their parent list, but even then I wouldn't recommend that.

Rewrite your code to keep a reference to the list.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Marcin, in that you shouldn't need this. But for whatever obscure reason, if you really really **really** do need this functionality, here's a decent start:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.index = 0
        self.next = None

class myContainer:
    def __init__(self, node):
        self.head = node
        self.length = 1
    def __setitem__(self, i, node):
        if i > self.length:
            raise ValueError("Index %s is too large. Cannot set item at that index. Current container length is %s" %(i, self.length))
        curr = self.head
        while i>0:
            curr = curr.next
            curr.next, node.next = node, curr.next
            node.index = curr.index + 1
        curr = node.next
        while curr is not None:
            curr.index += 1
            curr = curr.next
```